# Set default encoding to utf-8 using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, encoding, utf-8, oscommerce

I'm using oscommerce under xampp and I'm trying to set default encoding to utf-8, because some characters are messed up. My database is utf8-turkish-ci. Here's my htaccess code:

```
<filesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage tr-TR
</filesMatch>
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix these characters?

Edit: I checked my database and saw that it's utf8-unicode-ci

Comment: make sure that with phpmyadmin is displaying correct, I run this issue before but because the data was saved already wrong I couldn't display it correctly. if it is wrong on the database level, please play with collation on table/fields until you get it correct

Comment: another, also how do you connect to the database? try to add this: SET NAMES utf8;

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply. I've came across with SET NAMES on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489073/utf-8-turkish-character-on-oscommerce however I don't know where to put the code. I think the problem is related to a javascript file. because "Şubat" is a month in jquery-ui-i18n.js and jquery.ui.datepicker-tr.js files.

Comment: do you have access to the database?check my first comment

Comment: That first question mark character means the browser is already interpreting the page as UTF-8, however, you're not outputting valid UTF-8. .htaccess is not your problem. Somehow you're not outputting correctly encoded data. Since it seems to be working for *some* characters like "ü", this is beyond bizarre and may point to some serious data corruption issues.